# ubuntu How to change user to 'mysql'

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

### My Environment

Ubuntu 20
Mysql 8

### What I'm trying to do

I'm reading this article to change root password of mysql.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

```
B.3.3.2.2 Resetting the Root Password: Unix and Unix-Like Systems
...

The instructions assume that you start the MySQL server from the Unix login account that you normally use for running it. For example, if you run the server using the mysql login account, you should log in as mysql before using the instructions.
```

So it has to be a way to change OS user to 'mysql'

### What I did

so I did `sudo paasswd mysql`. I set the passwd

and... `cat /etc/shadow`

```
mysql:<newly created hash>:18650:0:99999:7:::
```

I tried `su - mysql`

```
su: warning: cannot change directory to /nonexistent: No such file or directory
```

and didn't change the user.

### The Question

what is the appropriate way to change OS user to `mysql`?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming, therefore it is off topic here on SO. The DBA sister site of SO provides help for database admin questions like this.

Comment: As root do this: `su - mysql`. There should not be a question for a password, and you should be logged on as user `mysql` (You can check using the command `id`)